# Compilation error: A net is not a legal lvalue in this context

Tags: verilog, asic, digital-design

I am a newbie to Verilog and had a problem while defining a `if-else` loop. The error message is

> A net is not a legal lvalue in this context" for all assign statements in the given code.

```
always @(adbar)  
if (adbar==1'b1)  
  begin   
    assign Z[0] = m_out[0];  
    assign Z[1] = m_out[1];  
    assign Z[2] = m_out[2];  
    assign Z[3] = X[5];  
    assign Z[4] = X[6];  
    assign Z[5] = X[7];  
    assign Z[6] = m_out[3]; 
    assign Z[7] = m_out[4];  
  end  
  else   
  begin    
    assign Z[0] = m_out[0];  
    assign Z[1] = m_out[1];  
    assign Z[2] = m_out[2];  
    assign Z[3] = X[3];  
    assign Z[4] = X[4];  
    assign Z[5] = X[5];   
    assign Z[6] = m_out[3];  
    assign Z[7] = m_out[4];  
  end  
endmodule
```

The full program is given below. All the modules have been properly defined and I am sure that the error is only in this part.

```
 module my_decoder (X,adbar, clear, clock, Z);  
 input [7:0] X;  
 input adbar; 
 input clear, clock;  
 output [7:0] Z;  

 wire clear, clock;  
 wire [7:0] Z; 
 wire [4:0] d_out;  
 wire [4:0] x_out;  
 wire [4:0] m_out;  
 wire [4:0] n_out;  
 wire sel1;  
 wire c_out1;  
 wire c_out2;  
 wire c_out3;  

 mux2_gate_1 \dut6[0].l4 (.in1 (x_out[0]), .in2 (n_out[0]), .sel (sel1), .o(m_out[0]));  
 mux2_gate_2 \dut6[1].l4 (.in1 (x_out[1]), .in2 (n_out[1]), .sel (sel1), .o(m_out[1]));  
 mux2_gate_3 \dut6[2].l4 (.in1 (x_out[2]), .in2 (n_out[2]), .sel (sel1), .o(m_out[2]));  
 mux2_gate_4 \dut6[3].l4 (.in1 (x_out[3]), .in2 (n_out[3]), .sel (sel1), .o(m_out[3]));  
 mux2_gate_5 \dut6[4].l4 (.in1 (x_out[4]), .in2 (n_out[4]), .sel (sel1), .o(m_out[4]));  

 always @(adbar)  
 if (adbar==1'b1)  
 begin   
   assign Z[0] = m_out[0];  
   assign Z[1] = m_out[1];  
   assign Z[2] = m_out[2];  
   assign Z[3] = X[5];  
   assign Z[4] = X[6];  
   assign Z[5] = X[7];  
   assign Z[6] = m_out[3]; 
   assign Z[7] = m_out[4];  
 end  
 else   
 begin    
   assign Z[0] = m_out[0];  
   assign Z[1] = m_out[1];  
   assign Z[2] = m_out[2];  
   assign Z[3] = X[3];  
   assign Z[4] = X[4];  
   assign Z[5] = X[5];   
   assign Z[6] = m_out[3];  
   assign Z[7] = m_out[4];  
 end  
endmodule
```

Comment: As a suggestion, avoid calling signals X or Z since these are signal values (0, 1, x, z) in Verilog. Actually I would suggest avoiding single letter names period (except perhaps for simple loop variables) and use more meaningful names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Verilog you can model combinational circuits using `assign` or `always`. You can't mix them together.

If you want to model using `assign`, you can replace your `always`-block with following construct:

```
assign Z = adbar ? {m_out[4:3], X[7:5], m_out[2:0]} : {m_out[4:3], X[5:3], m_out[2:0]};
```

If you want to model using `always`, remove `assign` keyword from assignments and change `Z` output type from `wire` to `reg`.